# Remove some strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove some strings in a dataframe that start with ***System:***

**My dataframe:**

```
       A          B                                                                C
  French      house   Blablabla System:Microsoft Windows XP; Browser:Chrome 32.0.1700;
 English      house               my address: 101-102 bd Charles de Gaulle 75001 Paris
  French  apartment                                                    my name is Liam
  French      house                                                       Hello George!
 English  apartment              System:Microsoft Windows XP; Browser:Chrome 32.0.1700;
```

**I tried:**

```
def remove_lines():

    df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r'(\s+)(System:).+','')

    return df
```

Nothing happens...

**Good output:**

```
       A          B                                                                C
  French      house                                                          Blablabla 
 English      house               my address: 101-102 bd Charles de Gaulle 75001 Paris
  French  apartment                                                    my name is Liam
  French      house                                                       Hello George!
 English  apartment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.C = df.C.str.replace('System:.*','')
df.C
# 0                                           Blablabla 
# 1    my address: 101-102 bd Charles de Gaulle 75001...
# 2                                      my name is Liam
# 3                                        Hello George!
# 4                                                     
# Name: C, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `split` function on `System` and pick the first part, like this:

```
In [1936]: df.C = pd.DataFrame(df.C.str.split('System').tolist())[0]
In [1937]: df
Out[1937]: 
         A          B                                                  C
0   French      house                                         Blablabla
1  English      house  my address: 101-102 bd Charles de Gaulle 75001...
2   French  apartment                                    my name is Liam
3   French      house                                      Hello George!
4  English  apartment
```